# c++ testing with input cases from text files

Tags: c++, testing

How can i test a c++ program with given input test cases?

For example an input like this

```
23 45 78 45 12 67 23 76 56 34
34 65 78 45 74 3  98 34 23 97
```

I want to be able to input these numbers from a text file into a program at run-time and test expected output. I cannot input thousands of numbers by hand in a console so are there any softwares that allow these kind of testing?

This is already being used in [InterviewStreet](http://interviewstreet.com), they use given test cases and match the expected output to test a program.

--Edit--

Is there any way i can pass values from a text file into `stdin` ?

Comment: No, just a simple gnu compiler on a mac.

Comment: Are you wanting to input these numbers through a text file or are you trying to use these as command-line arguments?

Comment: I want to input these numbers through a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a little bash script to run all of your tests.  An individual test would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
testprog < input1.txt > output1.txt
diff expected_output1.txt output1.txt
# examine the return code of diff to see if the files are different?
```